# Issue capturing non-numeric fields using piwik for Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, matomo

I am trying to monitor users of my R/Shiny app using piwik as described in this tutorial https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/usage-metrics.html

If the event.value is numeric, I can see the value selected in the Piwik dashboard, but if is a string nothing is shown. Is there

For example,

```
$(document).on('shiny:inputchanged', function(event) {
  if (event.name === 'input_name') {
    _paq.push(['trackEvent', 'input',
               'updates', event.name, event.value]);
    console.log(event.name);
    console.log(event.value);
  }
});
```

if the value of `input_name` is 1 the following will be in the visitor panel:

```
input - updates -input_name [1]
```

if the value of `input_name` is "string" the following will be in the visitor panel:

```
input - updates -input_name
```

Is there any way to get "string" to display in the panel, or for me to find it in the database or using the API?

Comment: When you say "Is there any way ... for me to find it in the database?", so you mean in addition to the regular [reporting API](https://developer.piwik.org/guides/reporting-api-tutorial) (detailed API reference [here](https://developer.piwik.org/api-reference/reporting-api))? Is that not doing what you'd expect?

Comment: The dashboard isn't doing what I expect when the input is a string rather than a numeric value. I expected the string to appear "input - updates -input_name [string]" in the same way as the number does "input - updates -input_name [1]". It isn't clear to me how I could query the api to retrieve the numeric/string value (that would also solve my problem)

Comment: It seems the dashboard defaults to only showing numeric results. There's a way to use the HTTP API, but you do have to spend time understanding it/getting someone who understands it to explain it to you. Using their demo website, you can, for example, query all events for the last year (only a handful) using: https://demo.piwik.org/index.php?module=API&method=Events.getAction&idSite=3&period=year&date=today&format=JSON&token_auth=anonymous. If you want to query only events with a certain label (e.g. `updates` in your case), you need to add the param `&label=updates` to the end of the URL

Comment: From what I could tell, the api seems to only give aggregated values